# Trying to use Oauth2 token with feign client and hystrix

Tags: spring, cloud, hystrix, netflix-feign, oauth-2.0

I am trying to call "ServiceB" from "ServiceA", both of the services are resource server, I am trying to make this inter service call through "Feign Client and OAuth2 toke" which is working fine with the below bean implmentation in Configuration class:

```
@Bean    
public RequestInterceptor requestTokenBearerInterceptor() {

    return new RequestInterceptor() {

        @Override
        public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {

            OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails)

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                    .getDetails();

            requestTemplate.header("Authorization",
                    "bearer " + details.getTokenValue());

        }

    };

}
```

When I am trying to use Feign client with fallback i.e. Hystrix without OAuth token(i.e. when none of services are Resource Server) that is also working fine.

But while trying to use three of these (i.e. Feignclient, Hystrix and OAuth2)all together, it is not working. Every time it is going to fallback method though all the services are up and running.

Below are my code:

App.java

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.EnableCircuitBreaker;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import        org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationDetails;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import feign.RequestInterceptor;
import feign.RequestTemplate;


@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class App 
{

/*@Autowired
@Qualifier("abc")
private GitHubClient gitHub;*/
@Autowired
private CallService callService;
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}
    @RequestMapping(value="/feign",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json")
public String contributors1(@RequestBody JSONObject payLoad) {
        String callservice2 = callService.callservice(payLoad);
        return callservice2;
}

@Bean
public RequestInterceptor requestTokenBearerInterceptor() {

    return new RequestInterceptor() {

        @Override
        public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {

            OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails)

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                    .getDetails();

            requestTemplate.header("Authorization",
                    "bearer " + details.getTokenValue());

        }

    };

}



}
```

Callervice.java

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CallService {


@Autowired
@Qualifier("abc")
private GitHubClient gitHub;

public String callservice(JSONObject payLoad){
    String forObject =gitHub.contributors(payLoad);
    return forObject;
}

}
```

HystrixWrappedClient.java

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.annotation.HystrixCommand;

@Component("abc")
public class HystrixWrappedClient implements GitHubClient{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("gitHubClient")
private GitHubClient gitHub;

@Override
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="failure")
public String contributors(JSONObject payLoad) {
    return gitHub.contributors(payLoad);
}

public String failure(JSONObject payLoad){
    System.out.println(payLoad);
    return "Failure";
}
}
```

GitHubClient.java

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@FeignClient("MockRestService")
interface GitHubClient {


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value =     "/test",consumes="application/json")
String contributors(@RequestBody JSONObject payLoad);

}
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For swagger documenation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- NEW -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Please suggest. Whenever trying to use Feignclient, OAuth2 and Hystrix all together it always going to Fallback method.

Answer (score 2):

Did you shared Spring Security context with Hystrix in some way?

Since **Spring Cloud Netflix 1.2.0** you can enable sharing of security context with Hystrix using i.e config param

`hystrix.shareSecurityContext: true`

Answer (score 1):

u can look into this http://kodgemisi.com/2017/02/use-securitycontext-feign-requestinterceptor/
Hystrix execute in another/different thread, transfer your security context by HystrixRequestVariableDefault